# Printing kwargs in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword-argument

I'm relatively new to Python and have recently come across kwargs. I think I understand them and how they work. However, when I try to print the key and the value using a for loop, it brings up a ValueError: Too many values to unpack.

```
def shop(**kwargs):
    sh = 1
    print ("Welcome to the shop!")
    for i, v in kwargs:
        print ("    ", i, ": ", v)
    while sh == 1:
        b = input ("What would you like to buy?").lower()
        if b == i:
            Player.gold -= v
            Player.inv_plus(i)
        elif b == "exit":
            sh = 0

shop(Stone=5, Potion=10)
```

Player.gold is just how much gold the player has, and Player.inv_plus(i) adds 1 to the item in the player's inventory. Though, that isn't important to the problem I'm having.

If I print kwargs without the for loop, it works fine. But that's not the format I want when printing it.

If someone could explain what I'm doing wrong I would be very grateful, as I am very confused as to why it isn't working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

kwargs is a dict, by default iterating over them only returns the keys. You need `kwargs.items()`.

```
for i, v in kwargs.items():
    print ("    ", i, ": ", v)
```

Comment: just adding a side note it's `kwargs.iteritems()` in python2